# Entry render not adding underline in iOS Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an Entry in Xamarin Forms and for Android, its displayed with an underline by default and when I test it for iOS it's always with a rectangle like this:

[image]

And I want it to be like just like in Android:

[image]

I used Custom render where I specified that I want an underline but its still displayed in a rectangle. This code doesn't work:

```
class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {             
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;                
        }
    }
}
```

I have solved this problem with the next code:

```
class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {             
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

            //Create borders(bottom only)
            CALayer border = new CALayer();
            float width = 2.0f;               
            border.BorderColor = Color.FromHex(ColorConstants.BlueHex).ToCGColor();
            border.Frame = new CGRect( 0, 40, 400, 2.0f);
            border.BorderWidth = width;

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(border);
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But still, don't understand why the previous code doesn't work, it should be simple as that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UITextBorderStyle/

The enum values for `UITextBorderStyle` are `Bezel`, `Line`, `None`, and `RoundedRect`. All of them (except for `None`) simply describe the style of the border that goes around the entire `UITextView`, so the `Line` value doesn't mean a single line, it means a solid line rectangle around the entire view, as opposed to a Bezel or rounded rectangle.

Comment: Well how to add just underline without all that adding background layers and bordering.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm not sure, in my app I just use the default border in my text views

Answer (score 0):

the implementation witch has solved the user question didn't work for me in these days, but this one has worked: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ae2e5ad-3cc4-4761-ac39-06e8d8842cf4/entry-bottom-line?forum=xamarinforms

as jmoerdyk gently suggested this link explains how to write a custom renderer for iOS to render an entry with a bottom line instead of a complete border. the color of the line will change when the entry has focus.

below the piece of code with some null checks:

```
 public class IOSBottomLineEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    private CALayer _borderLayer;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

        if (Element == null)
            return;
        
        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));

        e.NewElement.Unfocused += (_, _) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
        };
        e.NewElement.Focused += (_, _) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(245, 0, 47));
        };
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;
        
        if (Element == null)
            return;

        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
    }

    public override CGRect Frame
    {
        get { return base.Frame; }
        set
        {
            base.Frame = value;

            if (Control == null)
                return;
            
            if (Element == null)
                return;

            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
        }
    }

    private void DrawBorder(UIColor borderColor)
    {
        if (Frame.Height <= 0 || Frame.Width <= 0)
            return;

        if (_borderLayer == null)
        {
            _borderLayer = new CALayer
            {
                MasksToBounds = true,
                Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f),
                BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor,
                BorderWidth = 1.0f
            };

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_borderLayer);
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            _borderLayer.BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
            _borderLayer.Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Borderless entry using custom renderer/handler

```
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(BorderlessEntry), (handler, view) =>
    {
            //Remove the entry border
#if __IOS__
            handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
            handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#elif __ANDROID__
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#endif
   });
```

In xaml file, add boxview below entry :

```
<local:BorderlessEntry />
<BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray" WidthRequest="300"/>
```